# Audio delay setting on Netflix

Tags: netflix, audio

IS there a way to set a negative audio delay on Netflix? Similar to the audio/subtitle delay functionality on VLC.

I'm currently streaming my audio from my Windows PC via wifi to an Android device connected to my audio setup. The delay is about a second and makes watching Netflix using the current setup practically impossible.

There is mention online of a way to access a hidden menu using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right mouse click but this is no longer available.